# SQLite. Conditional search checking for column value existance

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have this kind of table

```
A B C D
1 2 3 4
1 2
    3 4
    3 4
```

A, B, C, D are columns.

In my code I know the rowid of fourth row, and I need to make a lookback from it fetching every row that has a value in column A. So I need to fetch rows 0 and 1:

```
1 2 3 4
1 2
```

So I currently try this

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE rowid < 3 AND A = "*"
```

But it doesn't work. I just need to check whether A exists.
How can I do that? In any other proramming lagnuange that would be something like

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE rowid < 3 AND Bool(A)
```

**How can I check the existance of column value?**

Thank you.

Comment: Removed MySQL tag because question is specifically about SQLite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE A IS NOT NULL;
```

EDIT:

If this returns all rows even when the column is empty, then the "empty" value is presumably not `NULL`.  Perhaps this will work:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE A IS NOT NULL and trim(A) <> ''
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can please tell me how can I get the last element of the query? if I set LIMIT 1, I get the first one.

Comment: If I use this query SELECT * FROM Table WHERE rowid < 4 AND A IS NOT NULL ORDER BY rowid DESC LIMIT 1 I somehow getthe element without A-value

Comment: Oh, I just double-checked. Unfortunately this is not working for me somehow at all.  I keep getting all the rows before rowid:

Comment: SELECT * FROM Table WHERE rowid < 164 AND A_column IS NOT NULL

Comment: This query retunrs ALL elements even when A_column value is empty.